# How to run a python script from linux terminal when it imports libraries like shodan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, shodan

```
root@kali:~# ./collecting_info_using_facets.py apache 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./collecting_info_using_facets.py", line 3, in <module>
    import shodan
ImportError: No module named shodan
```

I included path as `#!usr/bin/env` python but then also I cannot import shodan from the command line but I can run the same program from python3 IDLE.

Comment: Have you installed the shodan module?

Comment: are you sure you are running python3 and not 2? It seems you may have installed the shodan library for python3 (hence IDLE can run) but not for 2 (which I suspect you are running on the command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need to download the Python module called 'Shodan'. You don't seem to have it installed, that's why Python is returning the error: `ImportError: No module named shodan`

You can install Shodan for Python3 via:

```
pip3 install shodan
```

Or if you're running Python2, try:

```
pip2.7 install shodan
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I had it installed but i think the problem is related to namespace configuration.

Comment: What version of Python were you using? Also, it was an import error. You didn't have it downloaded for your specific Python version.

Comment: I am using Python 3. Bdw now its solved. I formatted my OS due to some reason and after that when I reinstalled the same using `python -m pip install shodan` so now its working.